# Insert string's each values into a single column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Here I want to insert the complete string each values into a column. For which I have written the following script:

**Example**:

**Table**: test

```
create table test
(
cola varchar(10),
colb varchar(max),
colc varchar(10)
);
```

**Note**: Now I want to insert records like the following by calling stored procedure:

```
cola   colb   colc
------------------
X1     M1     Z1
X1     M2     Z1
X1     M3     Z1
X1     M4     Z1
```

**Stored Procedure**: sptest

```
CREATE PROC sptest
@cola varchar(10),
@colb varchar(max),
@colc varchar(10)

AS

Declare @dynamic varchar(max)

    SET @dynamic =N'delete from test where colc='''+ @colc +'''';
    PRINT(@dynamic)
    EXEC(@dynamic)

    SET @dynamic =N'insert into test values('''+@cola+''','''+@colb+''','''+@colc+''')';
    PRINT(@dynamic)
    EXEC(@dynamic)

GO
```

**Note**: First I need to delete the records by check with the `colc` values and after that insert the records.

**Calling Function**:

```
EXEC sptest
@cola = 'X1',
@colb = 'M1,M2,M3,M4',
@colc = 'Z1'
```

**Note**: In the calling function as shown above the `colb` values must insert as shown in the above table. I am not getting how to insert the complete string each values in the `column colb`.

Comment: question does not make much sense.....

Comment: @MitchWheat, Please check updates.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic for this? There is no need for dynamic sql at all based on what you posted. It is not only unnecessary, it opens up your procedure to being vulnerable to sql injection. You should also ALWAYS name your columns in an insert statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL does not have any mechanism for automatically splitting a string of comma-separated values (your `@colb`-variable into multiple inserts. You will need to write some code to do this splitting yourself.

Basically, you should do something like this:

1. In a while loop, use `CHARINDEX` to determine the position of the next `,` in `@colb`. Store this position in a variable.
2. Use `SUBSTRING` to retrieve only the characters from `@colb` up to the position stored in (1).
3. Call `INSERT` with `@cola`, `@colc` and the value you extracted in (2).
4. Repeat until no more `,` found in @colc.