# Split comma separated string into temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following string variable to split into temp table.

**Example**:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX) = '10000,200000'
```

Now I want it to store in `#Temp` table.

Like this:

Table: `#Temp`

```
Cola     Colb
--------------
10000   200000
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-t-sql) among many many others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split multiple string's into multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264985/split-multiple-strings-into-multiple-columns) your Question only

Comment: yes,split the string,then pivot it.Insert the pivoted resultset into #temp table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your columns is not varchar

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
  Col1 int,
  Col2 int
)

DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX) = '10000,200000'
DECLARE @SQLString VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT #Temp Select ' + @Str

EXEC (@SQLString)
```

Comment: `DECLARE @SQLString VARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: except the declaration isn't valid and it doesn't execute as posted

Comment: `Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '#Temp'.` in SQL Server 2008 R2 environment I am getting this error

Comment: @Rajesh, I thought that was the error that you got. Have you ever sat down for a second a thought why you would received such an error? Maybe because the temp table does not exist? MAK asked how he could get values into table #Temp, and I gave him the answer. If you haven't created the temp table in your session, how do you expect the values to be inserted into that table? Create a #Temp table for yourself in your current session with 2 columns, and then execute it. And then you might have better success

Comment: @Jaques I had created the table but with only one column so its thrwing the error after your comment I created the table with two columns now its working fine Edited your Answer in order to cancel my down vote

Comment: @Rajesh, MAK never said that he wants to create a temp table from the string result. I quote "Now I want it to store in #Temp table.". If he wanted the temp table to be created he would've said so, so I'm not sure why you are so anal about this if the question was answered according to what MAK wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66445/discussion-between-rajesh-and-jaques).