# How to store semicolon separated long string into multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Basically due to restriction on live server, I cannot use text file so I need to hard code the data in T-SQL code.

So first I created string from text file like this:

```
("001122;Sale Item 1", "001123;Sale Item 23", "001124;Sale Item 24", .... )
```

I have this table structure:

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE(ProductCode INT NOT NULL, Description nvarchar(100) NOT NULL)
```

First I need to store code and description in a table variable. Once that's done, then I can easily map it to the physical table and update the records.

How can I achieve this something similar to:

```
insert into @Product(ProductCode, Description) 
values ("001122;Sale Item 1", "001123;Sale Item 23", "001124;Sale Item 24", .... )
```

```
 Code        Description

 001122      Sale Item1
 001123      Sale Item2
 001124      Sale Item3
```

Comment: Your ProductCode is INT, but you have leading zeros. They will be missing if you use datatype INT

Comment: And if you hardcode your values, why dont u just insert them your self manually? insert into @Product(ProductCode, Description) Values ('001122','Sale Item 1'), ('001123','Sale Item 23'),( '001124','Sale Item 24')

Comment: This does not seem you primary problem but rather a quirky workaround which you want to have fixed. Wouldn't it be better to solve your primary problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split multiple string's into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264985/split-multiple-strings-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: Sounds like a CSV to SQL conversion. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I crated a sample for you, please check this

```
declare @Questions varchar(100)= '"001122;Sale Item 1", "001123;Sale Item 23", "001124;Sale Item 24"'

DECLARE @myXML AS XML  = N'<H><r>' +Replace(@Questions, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r></H>'
 select @myXML

;WITH cte 
AS (
    SELECT CAST(N'<H><r>' +  Replace(Vals.id.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)') ,';' , '</r><r>') + '</r></H>' as XML) AS val 
    FROM @myXML.nodes('/H/r') AS Vals(id) 
)

,mycte1 as ( 
SELECT   distinct
    Replace( S.a.value('(/H/r)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') , '"', '') AS c1,   
    Replace( S.a.value('(/H/r)[2]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') , '"', '') AS c2

FROM cte CROSS APPLY val.nodes('/H/r') S(a)
)

select * from mycte1
```

The output will be

```
c1      c2
001123  Sale Item 23
001124  Sale Item 24
001122  Sale Item 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have fixed format like in example then you can achieve desired output simply using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(description, 0, CHARINDEX(';', DESCRIPTION, 0)) code,
    SUBSTRING(description, CHARINDEX(';', DESCRIPTION, 0)+1, LEN(DESCRIPTION)) Description  
FROM @Product
```

OUTPUT:

```
 code       Description
------------------------
001122      Sale Item 1
001123      Sale Item 23
001124      Sale Item 24
```

Comment: when i run your code then my output is in one  row not multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go matey:

```
DECLARE @MyString nvarchar(max) = '"001122;Sale Item 1", "001123;Sale Item 23", "001124;Sale Item 24"';

DECLARE @delimiter1   nvarchar(1)
      , @delimiter2   nvarchar(1)
      , @Start1       int
      , @End1         int
      , @Length       int
      , @cNEXTVALUE   nvarchar(1000)
      , @cNEXTVALUE2  nvarchar(1000)
      , @StringLength int;

DECLARE @Product TABLE ( 
                       ProductCode int NOT NULL
                     , Description nvarchar(100) NOT NULL );

SET @MyString = RTRIM(LTRIM(@MyString));
SET @MyString = REPLACE(@MyString, CHAR(13), '');
SET @MyString = REPLACE(@MyString, CHAR(10), '');

SET @delimiter1 = ';';
SET @delimiter2 = ',';
SET @MyString = REPLACE(@MyString, '"', '')+@delimiter2;
SET @StringLength = LEN(@MyString);

SELECT @Start1 = 0
     , @End1 = CHARINDEX(@delimiter1, @MyString, 1);

SELECT @Length = @End1 - @Start1;

WHILE @Length > 0
    BEGIN

        SET @cNEXTVALUE = SUBSTRING(@MyString, @Start1, @Length);
        SET @Start1 = @End1 + 1;

        SET @End1 = CHARINDEX(@delimiter2, @MyString, @Start1);
        SELECT @Length = @End1 - @Start1;

        SET @cNEXTVALUE2 = SUBSTRING(@MyString, @Start1, @Length);

        IF LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(@cNEXTVALUE))) > 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @Product
                       ( ProductCode
                       , Description
                       ) 
                VALUES
                       ( @cNEXTVALUE, @cNEXTVALUE2 );
            END;

        SET @Start1 = @End1 + 2;
        SET @End1 = CHARINDEX(@delimiter1, @MyString, @Start1);
        SELECT @Length = @End1 - @Start1;

    END;

SELECT *
  FROM @Product;
```